# div background color not effecting

Tags: html, css

i am trying to set div background color (class="markerDiv") but i am struggling to find, what i am missing. I am sure it will be something so small but need help. many thanks in advance

**HTML**:

```
<div id="map_Marker_Check_Block">
    <div class="markerDiv" id="maker_school">
        <label class="marker_label">School</label> <input class=
        "marker_ckeckbox" name="markerType" type="checkbox" value="school">
    </div><br>

    <div class="markerDiv" id="maker_gym">
        <label class="marker_label">Gym</label> <input class="marker_ckeckbox"
        name="markerType" type="checkbox" value="gym">
    </div><br>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.markerDiv {
    width: 14em;
    height: 48px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    clear: both;
    background-color: blue;
}

#map_Marker_Check_Block {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15em;
    height: 400px;
    top: 0;
    right: -12em;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#maker_school {
    background: url(../Icons/google_marker/Map_school.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bSXyX/ Seems to be working?

Comment: thats strange .. mm then why is not working in my code!!

Comment: Probably a caching issue, did you try to clear you cache?

Comment: a! i got it, i am adding background image to .markerDiv that is size of 48px X 48px! if i remove image from div; background color appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u should try to use 
    #map_Marker_Check_Block .markerDiv { background-color: blue; }

as the id overrules many classes.

or just background-color: blue!important; should work..